# stimulus.js live update field outside of controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

On a rails 6 installation, I have the following:

Controller:

```
# app/controllers/foo_controller.rb
def bar
  @items = [["firstname", "{{ FIRSTNAME }}"], ["lastname", "{{ LASTNAME }}"], ["company", "{{ COMPANY }}"]]
end
```

View:

```
# app/views/foo/bar.html.erb
<p>Quia <span data-field="firstname">{{&nbsp;FIRSTNAME&nbsp;}}</span> quibusd <span data-field="firstname">{{&nbsp;FIRSTNAME&nbsp;}}</span> am sint culpa velit necessi <span data-field="lastname">{{&nbsp;LASTNAME&nbsp;}}</span> tatibus  s impedit recusandae modi dolorem  <span data-field="company">{{&nbsp;COMPANY&nbsp;}}</span> aut illo ducimus unde quo u <span data-field="firstname">{{&nbsp;FIRSTNAME&nbsp;}}</span> tempore voluptas.</p>

<% @items.each do |variable, placeholder| %>
<div data-controller="hello">
  <input
  type="text"
  data-hello-target="name"
  data-action="hello#greet"
  data-field="<%= variable %>"
  value="<%= placeholder %>">
</div>
<% end %>
```

and the relevant [stimulus](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev) code (vanilla JS):

```
//app/javascript/controllers/hello_controller.js
import { Controller } from "stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = [ "name" ]

  greet() {
    var elements = document.body.querySelectorAll('[data-field="' + this.nameTarget.dataset.field + '"]');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].innerText = this.nameTarget.value;
    };
  }
}
```

Now, as you might have guessed, the idea is to generate one `<input>` field per item from the `@items` hash, pre-filled with the relevant value and "linked" with a `<span>`, which it updates on value change. So far, everything works.

Here's my issue though. This part is plain old dirty vanilla js, which doesn't feel too 'stimulusy':

```
var elements = document.body.querySelectorAll('[data-field="' + this.nameTarget.dataset.field + '"]');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].innerText = this.nameTarget.value;
};
```

Surely there's some way to improve this. Any suggestion as to how to refactor this code in a more elegant way would be most welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An approach would be to have two controllers, one for the 'thing that will change the content' (let's call this `content`) and another for the 'thing that will show any updated content somewhere else' (let's call this `output`).

Once you set up two controllers, it becomes a bit easier to reason about them as being discrete. One does something when a value updates from user interaction and the other should so something when it knows about an updated value.

Stimulus recommends [cross controller coordination with events](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/controllers#cross-controller-coordination-with-events). JavaScript event passing is a powerful, browser native, way to communicate across elements in the DOM.

### First, let's start with the simplest case in HTML only

- In general, it is good to think about the HTML first, irrespective of how the content is generated on the server side as it will help you solve one problem at a time.
- As an aside, I do not write Ruby and this question would be easier to parse if it only had the smallest viable HTML to reproduce the question.
- Below we have two `div` elements, one sits above and is meant to show the `name` value inside the `h1` tag and the `email` in the `p` tag.
- The second `div`  contains a two `input` tags and these are where the user will update the value.
- I have hard-coded the 'initial' data as this would come from the server in the first HTML render.

```html
<body>
  <div
    class="container"
    data-controller="output"
    data-action="content:updated@window->output#updateLabel"
  >
    <h1 class="title">
      Hello
      <span data-output-target="item" data-field="name">Joe</span>
    </h1>
    <p>
      Email:
      <span data-output-target="item" data-field="email">joe@joe.co</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div data-controller="content">
    <input
      type="text"
      data-action="content#update"
      data-content-field-param="name"
      value="Joe"
    />
    <input
      type="text"
      data-action="content#update"
      data-content-field-param="email"
      value="joe@joe.co"
    />
  </div>
</body>
```

### Second - walk through the event flow

- Once an `input` is updated, it will fire the `conten#update` event on change.
- The `data-content-field-param` is an [Action Parameter](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/actions#action-parameters) that will be available inside the `event.params` given to the class method `update` on the `content` controller.
- This way, the **one** class method has knowledge of the element that has changed (via the event) and the field 'name' to give this when passing the information on.
- The `output` controller has a separate action to 'listen' for an event called `content:updated` and it will listen for this event globally (at the `window`) and then call its own method `updateLabel` with the received event.
- The `output` controller has targets with the name `item` and each one has the mapping of what 'field' it should referent in a simple `data-field` attribute.

### Third - create the controllers

- Below, the `ContentController` has a single `update` method that will receive any fired input element's change event.
- The value can be gathered from the event's `currentTarget` and the field can be gathered via the `event.params.field`.
- Then a new event is fired with the `this.dispatch` method, we give it a name  of `updated` and Stimulus will automatically append the class name `content` giving the event name `content:updated`. As per docs - https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/controllers#cross-controller-coordination-with-events
- The `OutputController` has a target of name `item` and then a method `updateLabel`
- `updateLabel` will receive the event and 'pull out' the detail given to it from the `ContentController`'s dispatch.
- Finally, `updateLabel` will go through each of the `itemTargets` and see if any have the matching field name on that element's dataset and then update the `innerText` when a match is found. This also means you could have multiple 'name' placeholders throughout this controller's scoped HTML.

```js
class ContentController extends Controller {
  update(event) {
    const field = event.params.field;
    const value = event.currentTarget.value;
    this.dispatch('updated', { detail: { field, value } });
  }
}

class OutputController extends Controller {
  static targets = ['item'];

  updateLabel(event) {
    const { field, value } = event.detail;

    this.itemTargets.forEach((element) => {
      if (element.dataset.field === field) {
        element.innerText = value;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternate approach is to follow the [Publish-Subscribe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) pattern and simply have one controller that can both publish events and subscribe to them.

- This leverages the recommended approach of [Cross-controller coordination with events](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/controllers#cross-controller-coordination-with-events).
- This approach adds a single controller that will be 'close' to the elements that need to publish/subscribe and is overall simpler to the first answer.

### PubSubController - JS code example

- In the controller below we have two methods, a `publish` which will dispatch an event, and a `subscribe` which will receive an event and update the contoller's element.
- The `value` used by this controller is a `key` which will serve as the reference for what values matter to what subscription.

```js
class PubSubController extends Controller {
  static values = { key: String };

  publish(event) {
    const key = this.keyValue;
    const value = event.target.value;
    this.dispatch('send', { detail: { key, value } });
  }

  subscribe(event) {
    const { key, value } = event.detail;

    if (this.keyValue !== key) return;

    this.element.innerText = value;
  }
}
```

### PubSubController - HTML usage example

- The controller will be added to each input (to publish) and each DOM element you want to be updated (to subscribe).
- Looking at the `input`s you can see that they have the controller `pub-sub` and also an action (defaults to triggering when the input changes) to fire the publish method.
- Each `input` also contains a reference to its `key` (e.g email or name).
- Finally, the two spans that 'subscribe' to the content are triggered on the event `pub-sub:send` and pass the event to the `subscribe` method. These also have a key.

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="title">
      Hello
      <span
        data-controller="pub-sub"
        data-action="pub-sub:send@window->pub-sub#subscribe"
        data-pub-sub-key-value="name"
        >Joe</span
      >
    </h1>
    <p>
      Email:
      <span
        data-controller="pub-sub"
        data-action="pub-sub:send@window->pub-sub#subscribe"
        data-pub-sub-key-value="email"
        >joe@joe.co</span
      >
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input
      type="text"
      data-controller="pub-sub"
      data-action="pub-sub#publish"
      data-pub-sub-key-value="name"
      value="Joe"
    />
    <input
      type="text"
      data-controller="pub-sub"
      data-action="pub-sub#publish"
      data-pub-sub-key-value="email"
      value="joe@joe.co"
    />
  </div>
</body>
```